# .NET Core No OID value matches this name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I migrated from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET Core 3.1 and trying to verify signed data and I get the following error:

```
No OID value matches this name.
```

My code is the following:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] bytesToVerify = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(orData);

    byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signedData);

    rsa.FromXmlString(ConvertPemToXML(publicKeyPath));

    return success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"), signedBytes);
}
```

In .NET 4.7.2 I was not getting this error. Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: I think the error is in CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"). Try other simple name from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I know it is because of that. I tried SHA-512, SHA384 and still the same error